# What does this piece of text say? '''op I se ,+Ja^u!, noh jo huew moy''' '+)adxa I 'sno!^qo

Tags: cipher

> '''op I se ,+Ja^u!, noh jo huew moy'''
>
> '+)adxa I 'sno!^qo

Comment: (I actually liked it better with my title, since I actually do want an answer to the question I posed. But... shrug.)

Comment: Nice good example of lateral-thinking! We are really lacking those.

Comment: Actually, we shouldn't have labelled it as "text" -- that gave folks a bit of an extra hint.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To read this text:

> Turn everything upside down. Each character looks (approximately) like another when upside-down:
> [image]
>  The text reads
>           $\text{obvious, I expect,}$
>       $\ldots\text{how many of you }`\text{invert' as I do}\ldots$

My answer:

> iaw +oN

Comment: (Can one do a "hidden" block in a comment? There's a bit of a joke behind this that I'd like to share, but it would be a spoiler.)

Comment: @keshlam No, but anybody who's scrolled down far enough to read comments on answers is already committed to reading some spoilers anyway.

Comment: Well, I can put it this way: ..oap!^ asJa^u!.. punoJ6k)eq a+!ym uo +xa+ k)elq lle) o+ pasn sleu!wJa+ Ja+ndwo) esne)aq pa+eu!6!Jo s!y+ ... and I couldn't resist the pun.